# Rolling AR regressions in R

Tags: r, regression, arima, rolling-computation, forecast

I am managing a pure monthly time seires data with 348 observations.

Here is the reproducible sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

Y <- cumsum(rnorm(48))
date <- as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-04-01", 
                  "2012-05-01","2012-06-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-08-01",
                  "2012-09-01","2012-10-01","2012-11-01", "2012-12-01",
                  "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01","2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", 
                  "2013-05-01","2013-06-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-08-01",
                  "2013-09-01","2013-10-01","2013-11-01", "2013-12-01",
                  "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01","2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", 
                  "2014-05-01","2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-08-01",
                  "2014-09-01","2014-10-01","2014-11-01", "2014-12-01",
                  "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", 
                  "2015-05-01","2015-06-01",  "2015-07-01", "2015-08-01",
                  "2015-09-01","2015-10-01","2015-11-01", "2015-12-01"))

data<-data.frame(date,Y)
```

I am replicating a paper and calculating "shock". The quoted procedure is as follows:

"Shocks in each of these series are calculated by an AR(2) model over a rolling window of 10 months that ends in month n.The shock in month n+1 denoted dYn+1 is the difference between the actual value of the series and its predicted value using the slope coefficients estimated over the preceding 10 months. Thus, our method is forward-looking, providing out-of-sample prediction errors."

The AR(2) model with a trend term according to original authors is as follows:

```
Yt = a0 + a1*Yt-1 + a2*Yt-2 + a3*Tt+ residualt
where Tt is the serial number of the observation, to account for a time trend in these series.
```

If my objective is to calculate the mean in 11st using previous 10 obs, I can simply call the following:

```
Mean= slide_index_dbl(Y, date, mean, .before = months(10), .after = months(-1), .complete = T)
```

However, in this case, the objective is to run a AR model using all previous 10 obs and use this estimated model to predict 11st one, the final ouput is the actual value in 11st minus the predicted one. Put it simply, I need to construct a function to achieve this goal instead of using "mean" function in previous example.

Once I finish this function(let's call it AR_2), we can call it inside the slider.

```
library(slider)

data1<-data%>%
  mutate(Shock= slide_index_dbl(Y, date, AR_2, .before = months(10), .after = months(-1), .complete = T))
```

```
   Date       Y     N  Predict    Shock
2012-01-01   0.15   1    0.2     -0.005
2012-02-01   0.4    2    0.33      0.07
2012-03-01   0.39   3    0.44     -0.05
... 
2012-10-01   1.85   10   2.1      -0.25
2012-11-01   1.7    11   1.5       0.2   
2012-12-01   3.46   12   4.1      -0.65
```

Let me illustrate my question using above sample data I make up. The final output is Shock, which is the difference between Y(actual data) and Predicted Y. With that being said, the question is how to get Predicted Y. Before we predict Y, we need to first train a AR model by feeding previous 10 months data. Once you get this model, you can predict 11st obs with this model and that would be Predicted Y. The final tast is to calculate the difference between it with actual Y, which is called shock.

The numerical example is as follows:in order to get output 0.074 for 2012-11-01, I need to train a AR(2) model using all previous 10 months data from 2012-01-01 to 2012-10-01, that is from 0.15 to 1.85 for Y and 1 to 10 for N. Once I've trained this model, I use it to predict new value (0.2) in 2012-11-01. The final output "Shock" is the difference between actual obs in 2012-11-01 with the predicted one (0.15-0.2=0.05).

Similarly, in order to get output 0.08 for 2012-12-01, I need to train a AR(2) model using all previous 10 months data from 2012-02-01 to 2012-11-01, that is from 0.4 to 1.7 for Y and 2 to 11 for N. Once I've trained this model, I use it to predict new value (4.1) in 2012-12-01. The final output "Shock" is the difference between actual obs in 2012-12-01 with the predicted one (3.46-4.1=-0.65).

I do not know how to write such a function(AR_2) and call it in slide_index_dbl. Please remember there is a trend term a3*Tt in AR_2, I not sure how to model that.

The following is what I have tried. I use lm to implement a AR moel instead of arima. This is because I do not know how to use arima to predict new value. If anyone are familar with arima or Arima function, go use that.

```
Intercept_extract_lm<-function(x){
  N<-rep(1:10)
  model<-lm(x~ lag(x,1)+ lag(x, 2)+N)
  coef(model)["(Intercept)"]
}

Log_1_extract_lm<-function(x){
  N<-rep(1:10)
  model<-lm(x~ lag(x,1)+ lag(x, 2)+N)
  coef(model)["Lag_1"]
}

Log_2_extract_lm<-function(x){
  N<-rep(1:10)
  model<-lm(x~ lag(x,1)+ lag(x, 2)+N)
  coef(model)["Lag_2"]
}


drift_extract_lm<-function(x){
  N<-rep(1:10)
  model<-lm(x~ lag(x,1)+ lag(x, 2)+N)
  coef(model)["N"]
}

data1<-data%>%
  mutate(Lag_1=lag(Y,1),Lag_2=lag(Y,2),N=1:n(),
         a1=slide_index_dbl(Y, Date, Log_1_extract_lm, .before = months(10), .after = months(-1), .complete = T),
         a2=slide_index_dbl(Y, Log_2_extract_lm, .before = months(10), .after = months(-1), .complete = T),
         drift=slide_index_dbl(Y, Date, drift_extract_lm, .before = months(10), .after = months(-1), .complete = T),
         Intercept = slide_index_dbl(Y, Date, Intercept_extract_lm, .before = months(10), .after = months(-1), .complete = T),
         Predict=Intercept+a1*Lag_1+a2*Lag_2+drift,
         Shock=Y-Predict)
```

I understand that the biggest problem in my code is it can take only one input argument in slider, but I am using four in all the custom functions defined (Y and lag_1 and lag_2 and N). Unlike previous example, we just calculate rolling mean of one single variable, in this case, in order to run such a regression, we need four variables in each rolling window, but slider only has one variable input. Even we edit the "extract" function to reduce four variables to two ( lag_1 and lag_2 can be writted as lag(Y,1) and lag(Y,2), we still have Y and N two variables input)

As for the trend term, from my understanding, for example, for 2012-11-01, in order to run regression, I need previous 10 minths N, that is 1,2,3....10, that is serial number of obs. For 2012-12-01, it should be also include a N from 1,2,3...10, however, based on my code, it is 2,3,4...11. But adding constant of 1 (2,3...11 vs 1,2,...10) doesn't affect regression coefficient, right? Honestly, I am not sure about trend term in this case, please feel free to change it if you understand orginal authors.

Comment: Hey, Anil. I have edited  the question. This is the question I refer in the other one. The original procedure is to roll 60 months, but I change to 10 considering my limited sample. The length of final output for each month is just 1. I just do not know how to write such AR_2 function inside slider.

Comment: Anil, I am checking back if you have any idea about this question? I saw your explanation in my last question and you use mean(arima(x,c（1,0，0）0$residuals) to extract a value with length of 1. However, when I check back to the procedure, it seems that this is not what original authors want.

Comment: Anil, please see my edited question. This question may require some background in time series analysis since I will use ARIMA (AR model) modeling. Let me know your confusion.

Comment: Anil, I have edited last several paragraphs. It would be easier if you have experience in modeing ARIMA model in R. The difficulty is to predict new value using estimated ARIMA model fed by previous 10 obs. The rest of it is same as last question when we want to calculate mean of previous obs.

Comment: Anil, I unload what I have tried. I understand what my error means, I just don't know how to fix it. Becuase in slider, the variable is Y so I just use previous 10 Y, however, in regression, I also need to use previous 10 Lag_1 and Lag_2.

Comment: I do not follow why you say there are more than one value per month. It is monthly data, so there is only one Y for each month. For each rolling window, it should have 10 months and 10 Y, Lag_1, Lag_2, N respectively. The N should always be a serial numbers, say 1 to 10, 2 to11.... I have edited my custom functions. However, there is still error saying the length is different("N")

Comment: Thank you Anil. The biggest challenge is the trend term cannot be modeled into arima function. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: Derek, `Trend` is by default modelled into `arima` function the first number in order argument here does exactly that.  2 means here we are using AR2 modelling.  [see this](https://nwfsc-timeseries.github.io/atsa-labs/sec-tslab-autoregressive-ar-models.html).  Please also [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), if it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this.  Your problem  of lagged 2 [A(2) Model] will be catered by `order = c(2,0,0)` and you don't have to do it explicitly.  `arima()` function is used in conjunction with `predict()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
Y <- cumsum(rnorm(48))
date <- as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-04-01", 
                  "2012-05-01","2012-06-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-08-01",
                  "2012-09-01","2012-10-01","2012-11-01", "2012-12-01",
                  "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01","2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", 
                  "2013-05-01","2013-06-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-08-01",
                  "2013-09-01","2013-10-01","2013-11-01", "2013-12-01",
                  "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01","2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", 
                  "2014-05-01","2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-08-01",
                  "2014-09-01","2014-10-01","2014-11-01", "2014-12-01",
                  "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", 
                  "2015-05-01","2015-06-01",  "2015-07-01", "2015-08-01",
                  "2015-09-01","2015-10-01","2015-11-01", "2015-12-01"))

data <- data.frame(date,Y)

library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = F)
library(slider)

data %>% 
  mutate(pred_roll_10 = slide_index_dbl(Y, .i = date, 
                                        ~ predict(arima(.x, c(2,0,0), method = 'ML'),1)$pred[1], 
                                        .before = months(10),
                                        .after = months(-1),
                                        .complete = T),
         shock = Y - pred_roll_10)
#> Warning in log(s2): NaNs produced

#> Warning in log(s2): NaNs produced

#> Warning in log(s2): NaNs produced

#> Warning in log(s2): NaNs produced
#>          date          Y pred_roll_10        shock
#> 1  2012-01-01 -0.5604756           NA           NA
#> 2  2012-02-01 -0.7906531           NA           NA
#> 3  2012-03-01  0.7680552           NA           NA
#> 4  2012-04-01  0.8385636           NA           NA
#> 5  2012-05-01  0.9678513           NA           NA
#> 6  2012-06-01  2.6829163           NA           NA
#> 7  2012-07-01  3.1438325           NA           NA
#> 8  2012-08-01  1.8787713           NA           NA
#> 9  2012-09-01  1.1919184           NA           NA
#> 10 2012-10-01  0.7462564           NA           NA
#> 11 2012-11-01  1.9703382    0.6951079  1.275230339
#> 12 2012-12-01  2.3301521    2.0524671  0.277684986
#> 13 2013-01-01  2.7309235    1.9333295  0.797594017
#> 14 2013-02-01  2.8416062    2.0486834  0.792922863
#> 15 2013-03-01  2.2857651    1.9959595  0.289805588
#> 16 2013-04-01  4.0726782    1.7514948  2.321183420
#> 17 2013-05-01  4.5705287    3.6469980  0.923530738
#> 18 2013-06-01  2.6039116    4.0585260 -1.454614411
#> 19 2013-07-01  3.3052675    1.6480334  1.657234048
#> 20 2013-08-01  2.8324760    2.9543635 -0.121887466
#> 21 2013-09-01  1.7646523    2.8739943 -1.109341911
#> 22 2013-10-01  1.5466774    2.7845341 -1.237856702
#> 23 2013-11-01  0.5206730    2.5894221 -2.068749114
#> 24 2013-12-01 -0.2082182    1.3652172 -1.573435497
#> 25 2014-01-01 -0.8332575    0.3654956 -1.198753080
#> 26 2014-02-01 -2.5199508   -0.5625776 -1.957373251
#> 27 2014-03-01 -1.6821638   -2.6388755  0.956711703
#> 28 2014-04-01 -1.5287907   -0.7131115 -0.815679154
#> 29 2014-05-01 -2.6669276   -1.2140023 -1.452925253
#> 30 2014-06-01 -1.4131127   -2.6421098  1.228997135
#> 31 2014-07-01 -0.9866485   -1.0140132  0.027364706
#> 32 2014-08-01 -1.2817199   -0.8209904 -0.460729511
#> 33 2014-09-01 -0.3865943   -1.2655968  0.879002504
#> 34 2014-10-01  0.4915392   -1.1977841  1.689323273
#> 35 2014-11-01  1.3131203   -0.4463373  1.759457622
#> 36 2014-12-01  2.0017605    0.9931931  1.008567426
#> 37 2015-01-01  2.5556782    1.7819117  0.773766509
#> 38 2015-02-01  2.4937665    2.3699293  0.123837184
#> 39 2015-03-01  2.1878038    2.1804620  0.007341787
#> 40 2015-04-01  1.8073328    1.5452418  0.262091026
#> 41 2015-05-01  1.1126258    1.2644697 -0.151843849
#> 42 2015-06-01  0.9047086    0.2974574  0.607251157
#> 43 2015-07-01 -0.3606878    0.7761950 -1.136882824
#> 44 2015-08-01  1.8082682   -1.1719233  2.980191448
#> 45 2015-09-01  3.0162302    1.9584189  1.057811310
#> 46 2015-10-01  1.8931216    2.5356767 -0.642555104
#> 47 2015-11-01  1.4902368    1.2115509  0.278685838
#> 48 2015-12-01  1.0235814    1.4319100 -0.408328595
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Anil. I have edited it. The biggest confusion is that N is not a single value, it is same as Y, lag_1, lag_2, it has length of 10.  The main challenge right now is slider only has one input but my custom function has 4 (Y,lag_1,lag_2,N) or 2 (Y and N if we represents lag_1 and lag_2 by lag(Y,1) and lag(Y,2) )